# mySQL INSERT query with condition

Tags: mysql

I have two table: `employee` and `privremeno` and the both of them contains column `jmbg`. I want insert in `employee` (two columns) data from `privremeno` (two columns) so that data would be inserted in row where `jmbg` in `employee` is equal (the same) to `jmbg` in `privremeno`.
Something like:

```
INSERT INTO vg_pka.employee (stazDani, godZivota) select  ukstaz, gz from
vg_pka.privremeno where vg_pka.privremeno.jmbgl = vg_pka.employee.jmbg;
```

How to do that?

Comment: show two columns names

Answer (score 0):

you have to use update to inser values to existing table . I cant get your correct requirement . But the below is the syntax you have to use.

```
update table_name set = 'value' where (your condition)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a join:

```
INSERT INTO 
    vg_pka.employee (stazDani, godZivota) 
SELECT  
    ukstaz, gz 
FROM
    vg_pka.privremeno p 
INNER JOIN
    vg_pka.employee e
ON
    p.jmbgl = e.jmbg;
```